# How to remove the decimal point in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way for removing decimals in a pandas dataframe?

Example Data:

```
1.10
2.20
3.30
4.40
```

Expected result:

```
110
220
330
440
```

Comment: Are they all just *100?

Comment: yes they are all the same figure

Comment: I don't use pandas, but I assume this is basic Python? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm importing a CSV file, and then singling out the column that I am looking to modify.  using df.['column'].replace. But I believe the issue is replacing '.' with nothing ('') is causing it to not return an error but simply do nothing to the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using as `df['col'] = (df['col']*100).astype(int)`
 as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1.10, 2.20, 3.30, 4.40]})
df['col'] = (df['col']*100).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col
0  110
1  220
2  330
3  440
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Great! `Happy Coding`.

Answer (score 1):

If - as your comment suggests - the data just all needs to be multiplied by 100...

```
df['columnName'] = df['columnName'].apply(lambda x: x*100)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Py4D No problem! If my solution solved your problem would you mind marking it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

As far I am aware pandas always give you numbers on that format. Well if you are just want to change it for look or preference purposes then. Here is something for  you suppose you already the name of that column is amount;

```
 df['amount']= (df['amount']).astype(str).str.replace('.', '')
```

Please note that the type of that column has been changed to **string** you can now retransform it into int.